# JQuery: Getting data from child elements

Tags: jquery

Markup:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="item-list" data-id="1">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="item-list" data-id="2">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="item-list" data-id="3">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

In JQuery, i would select link 1 and it should be able to fetch the data-id of link1. I tried

```
$('.item-list').click(function(){
 var link = $(this);
 alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

It doesn't have any result.

Oh. the list gets generated after the page is loaded. I am querying the DB to get the list. Also, it is also possible for the list to change, depending on how the user filters the dB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the list is generated after the page is loaded, the `.click` binding might not work. Maybe you can try `.live`, like so:

```
$('.item-list').live('click', function(){
   var link = $(this);
   alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

**EDIT:**

What I always seem to forget :) as of jQuery 1.7, `.live()` is deprecated. You should use `.on()` like so:

```
 $("body").on("click",".item-list",function(){
    var link = $(this);
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Comment: since jquery 1.7  **.live()** is deprecated. Use **.on()** instead.

Comment: dude this is wrong way of using on if the content is loaded after attaching event to DOM

Comment: I had an error in my .on() example, as @Somebodyisintrouble correctly mentioned. I edited the example. You can also look at his answer!

Answer (score 2):

use .on because live is deprecated and also put your code inside `document.ready()`

```
$(function(){  //short form of document.ready        
    $("body").on("click",".item-list",function(){
        var link = $(this);
        alert($(this).data('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: My example isn't exactly what my data is structured. What if it was .item-list is in a table?

Comment: No problem until .item-list is inside body

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').on('click', '.item-list', function() {
  var link = $(this);
  alert(link.attr('data-id'));
});
```

See if that works

Comment: Wouldn't it be link.attr('data-id') then?